# Javascript + XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

have some javascript that looks at the 'comment' part of the below XML, i'm trying to add another rule where: 'is-public' needs to have the value: 'true'. I have tried adding `public[count] = $j(this).find('is-public').text("true")();` which doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#ticket_fields_NONE').attr("disabled", true);
  //Check to see if there isn't already a value
  if(!$j('input#ticket_fields_NONE').val()) {

    //setting the DOM Object to attach the queue to
    var para = $j("select#ticket_assignee_id");
        var roleID = new Array();
    var count = 0;
    var commentAuthor = new Array();
    var ticketCreated = new Array();
var public = new Array();

//beginning of queue
        para.queue("testQueue", function( next ){$j.get('/tickets/{{ticket.id}}.xml', 
            function(ticketCreateAt) {
                $j(ticketCreateAt).find('comment').each(function() {
                    ticketCreated[count] = $j(this).find('created-at').text();
    public[count] = $j(this).find('is-public').text("true")();
                    commentAuthor[count] = $j(this).find('author-id').text();
                    var timeUNIX = new Date();
                    timeUNIX.setISO8601(ticketCreated[count]);
                    ticketCreated[count] = Date.parse(timeUNIX)/1000;
                    //displays in the sidewidget it can be removed.
                    count++;
                });
```

**XML:**

```
 <ticket>
    <assigned-at type="datetime" nil="true"/>
    <assignee-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <base-score type="integer">720</base-score>
    <created-at type="datetime">2012-07-17T10:38:03+10:00</created-at>
    <current-collaborators nil="true"/>
    <current-tags>
    topic-general_site_tech-facebook_question training_tim via_contact_form
    </current-tags>
    <description>test</description>
    <due-date type="datetime" nil="true"/>
    <entry-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <external-id nil="true"/>
    <group-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <initially-assigned-at type="datetime" nil="true"/>
    <latest-recipients nil="true"/>
    <nice-id type="integer">218</nice-id>
    <organization-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <original-recipient-address nil="true"/>
    <priority-id type="integer">0</priority-id>
    <recipient nil="true"/>
    <requester-id type="integer">237738133</requester-id>
    <resolution-time type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <solved-at type="datetime" nil="true"/>
    <status-id type="integer">0</status-id>
    <status-updated-at type="datetime">2012-07-17T10:38:03+10:00</status-updated-at>
    <subject/>
    <submitter-id type="integer">214034168</submitter-id>
    <ticket-type-id type="integer">0</ticket-type-id>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2013-04-19T12:53:45+10:00</updated-at>
    <updated-by-type-id type="integer">0</updated-by-type-id>
    <via-id type="integer">5</via-id>
    <score type="integer">720</score>
    <problem-id nil="true"/>
    <has-incidents type="boolean">false</has-incidents>
    <comments type="array">
    <comment>
    <author-id type="integer">237738133</author-id>
    <created-at type="datetime">2012-07-17T10:38:03+10:00</created-at>
    <is-public type="boolean">true</is-public>
    <type>Comment</type>
    <value>test</value>
    <via-id type="integer">5</via-id>
    <attachments type="array"/>
    </comment>
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's pretty clear from the markup that he's using jQuery

Comment: what are you expecting the value of `public[count]` to be

Comment: Hi Arun, value should be 'true' not sure if I should even be using [count]?

Comment: so you want to iterate through only public commnets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through only public comments then change

```
$j(ticketCreateAt).find('comment')
```

to

```
$j(ticketCreateAt).find('comment:has(is-public:contains("true"))')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/lPpm55nxGCuph6CpnaVf?p=preview)

Comment: @Charlie is it for access restriction? like the logged in user has access only to public commnets

Comment: Hey Arun, it's actually just to calculate the first reply time on tickets in ZD. But if the reply is made 'private' then it doesn't count as a reply. But now that I can just look at public comments, and with your modification means it works!

Comment: @Charlie in that case it is ok, if it was for access control then client side filtering is a bad idea

Comment: @Charlie if the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted, because it looks like none of your question has a accepted answer, it will look bad for your profile